# Remote control widget

Tags: applications, launcher, app-widgets

I am looking to develop a remote control widget on the Android platform which is similar in concept to the **JustABlip remote control widget** on iOS. So wanted to know whether the android architecture can support such kind of widget development.

https://itunes.apple.com/hk/app/justablip-remote-control-widget/id944174429?l=zh&mt=8

[image]

Comment: The Smart Remote/Peel remote apps work well. can't remember, but one of them is a messenger-style bubble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like that are off-topic, man. However, there is already an app like it.

## ONLY ONE CAN REMAIN

Ahem,
Try the [Smart Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adi.remote.phone&hl=en_GB) app. Now, I know it's by Samsung (So you are choosing to install crapware) but it Has all sorts of features, including having the remote-get this!- in the notification tray. Try it out some time.

*Disclaimer- An android phone may need an IR blaster, or the target device to control allow control over the internet. Like a sky+HD box.*

Suprsingly useful: http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/03/18/how-to-use-the-galaxy-note-4-as-a-remote-control/

Comment: @stud91 No problem.

Comment: But isn't Samsung discontinuing IR blasters? Your app might be for personal use only or have a very short shelf life.

Comment: @user145490 true, but it can work on non-samsung phones. Also, it's been out for quite some time, so it already has a decent shelf life. Samsung may stop supporting IR, but I doubt it will just be cut off by other devs too.